# Gauss hypergeometric series and hyperbolic functions- proof

Tags: hypergeometric-function, trigonometric-series

The following two equations seem to be numerically equal:

$\frac{{{y^{14}}{2^F}1\left( {1,\frac{{15}}{8},\frac{{23}}{8},{y^8}} \right)}}{{15\;{2^F}1\left( {1,\frac{1}{8},\frac{9}{8},{y^8}} \right)}} - {(1 - x)^{7/4}} = 0$

${{{\sinh }^{ - 4}}\left( {\frac{{0.88137}}{x}} \right) - (1 - {y^8}) = 0}$

At $x = 0,\;y = 1\;{\rm{and}}\;{\rm{at}}\;x = 1,\;y = 0$

The second equation is a well known equation in statistical mechanics with $y$ known as magnetization and  $x$ is a scaled temperature $(T/{T_c})$ . The first equation containing Gauss hypergeometric series was derived by solving an ordinary differential equation.

x is positive and ranges from 0 to 1.Is it possible to prove that both eqns are identical?

Comment: What is special about 0.88137? Seems like a strange thing to have in an exact equality

Comment: When x =1, this value of 0.88137 indicates the value of  sinh-1(1). In fact, sinh(2J/kT) =1 denotes the condition for the phase transition where J denotes the interaction energy and k is the Boltzmann constant, T being the absolute  temperature.